# Not able to recieve Remote Notifications in Xamarin.Android when the application is closed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I used this link for my app.
     https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/
          // This is my GCM Listener Service
      using Android.App;
     using Android.Content;
     using Android.OS;
    using Android.Gms.Gcm;
    using Android.Util;

```
namespace Kites
{
[Service (Exported = false), IntentFilter (new [] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived (string from, Bundle data)
    {
        var message = data.GetString ("message");
        Log.Debug ("MyGcmListenerService", "From:    " + from);
        Log.Debug ("MyGcmListenerService", "Message: " + message);
        SendNotification (message);
    }

    void SendNotification (string message)
    {
        var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(Login));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder (this)
            .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.kiteslogo)
            .SetContentTitle ("GCM Message Test")
            .SetContentText (message)
            .SetAutoCancel (true)
            .SetDefaults (NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
            .SetContentIntent (pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify (0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}


}
```

This Is my Instance Id Listener Service
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
     using Android.Gms.Gcm.Iid;

```
  namespace Kites
 {
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" })]
class MyInstanceIDListenerService : InstanceIDListenerService
{
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var intent = new Intent (this, typeof (RegistrationIntentService));
        StartService (intent);
    }
}
}
```

This is My Registration Intent Service

```
 namespace Kites
  {
[Service(Exported = false)]
class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
{
    static object locker = new object();

    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent (Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance (this);
                var token = instanceID.GetToken (
                    "SENDER_ID", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                SendRegistrationToAppServer (token);
                Subscribe (token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
            return;
        }
    }

    void SendRegistrationToAppServer (string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation here as needed.
    }

    void Subscribe (string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(this);
        pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);
    }
}
 }
```

This is the Message Sender Program i Use To Send Message
    {
                {
                   class Program
                   {
                     public const string API_KEY =
                 "API KEY";
                        public const string MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jGcmData = new JObject();
        var jData = new JObject();

        jData.Add("message", MESSAGE);
        jGcmData.Add("to", "/topics/global");
        jGcmData.Add("data", jData);

        var url = new Uri("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                    "Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);

                Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync(url,
                    new StringContent(jGcmData.ToString(), Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
                        .ContinueWith(response =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(response);
                            Console.WriteLine("Message sent: check the client device notification tray.");
                        }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to send GCM message:");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sender Id And API KEY are corrrect but still im not able to recieve my notifications.

When i Try to send a message, in my messagesender.exe its confirmed that The message has been sent . Please check the device Tray.
I Have followed everything correctly. Still i am not reciving any messages.

Comment: have you followed the program's flow to check if any of the calls fails? check if you get the instance id, check if you correctly sent the registration to your server and check if the server, after receiving the id sent correctly the message. Also remember to add the pertinent permissions to the android manifest.

Comment: Yes Everything is Done correctly. I have Checked It. But Still I can't receive messages. Even Added Permissions To Manifest .

Comment: Try to deploy your application in release mode.

Comment: @BhavinSurelia It Worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and update necessary following things for your code

- Add Permission to manifest file.
- debug and check coverage code.
- recreate api key -- maybe you create it wrong

or You should use FCM [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: Yes. I was With a issue with my android manifest. It Helped me.

Comment: But when i close my application from my multitasking app manager i dont recieve any notifications. i need some help on that

Comment: 1. are you using device or emulator? 2. check server connectivity maybe your server didn't get request